# How can I fire an event when an element comes into view using steady.js?

Tags: javascript, steady.js

I'm trying to use **steady.js** to fire an event when an element comes into view. My element has the classname `someclass`.

```
var steady = new Steady({
    throttle: 100,
    handler: function(el) {
        console.log('woo!')
    }
});

steady.addTracker('.someclass-top', function(){
    console.log('Top of our someclass element')
});
```

After scrolling past the .someclass element, I expect the tracker for '.someclass-top' to fire. However nothing happens.

Comment: Is Steady a native function?

Comment: @true No, it's a library, see the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can accomplish what you want with Steady

```
var el = document.querySelector('.someclass'); // cache element for better performance

var steady = new Steady({
    throttle: 100,
    handler: function(el, done) {
        console.log('woo!');

        // this important to tell Steady that you finished processing so it can call you later
        done();
    }
});

steady.addTracker('someclassIsVisible', function(){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
       rect.top    >= 0
    && rect.left   >= 0
    && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
});

steady.addCondition('someclassIsVisible', true);
```